# if/else iterating over same variable in two different for loops

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

Is there a better (more concise) way of iterating over the same collections objects in an if/else condition than the following:

```
bool condition = DetermineConditionValue();

if(condition)
{
    foreach(var v in variables)
    {
        PerformAction(v);
    }
else
{
    foreach(var v in variables)
    {
        PerformAnotherAction(v);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to avoid writing the loop twice?

Comment: Use pointer to function

Comment: I think this question will end up flagged as attracting too many opinions, rather than an actual answer. 'Better' is inherently subjective, and depends on what you want to do. The way you're currently doing it is probably better performance-wise than alternatives, though.

Comment: Well, you could put the `if` statement inside your `foreach` loop, but really I wouldn't get too concerned. As long as the code seems logical when you read it.

Comment: By better I mean more concise way without having to sacrifice performance.

Comment: @Ben I don't want to be executing the condition with each iteration of the loop as the condition doesn't change.

Comment: On what kind of rotten potato do you want to run your code that you worry about performance differences when having the `if` inside the loop? Two words: Branch prediction. Okay, two more words: Speculative execution. Also, you would need to put the performance cost of `if` in relation to the performance cost of executing Perform(Another)Action, which probably alone makes the whole performance cost of `if` inside the loop insignificant...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`Action<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Action<YourParameterTypeHere> actionToDo = DetermineConditionValue()
      ? PerformAction 
      : PerformAnotherAction;

foreach(var v in variables)
{
    actionToDo(v);
}
```